# Cannot add Linked file on a Server to R.raw

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm trying to add a file from our fileserver to my Android Project

```
\\server\common\applicationname\DemoDatabase\demo.sqlite
```

When I add this to the Project I am adding it in res/raw as "demodatabase"

When I then Clean and rebuild, in the R.java file it doesn't add my `demodatabase`

If I copy the file from the Server directly into the Raw directory, and then choose to link it, then it gets added to the R.java file.

```
"C:\Development\Android\project\res\raw\demo.sqlite"
```

and choose to link and select this file as `demo`

```
public static final class raw {
    public static final int demo=0x7f040000;
}
```

the snippet from my .project file looks like this

```
<linkedResources>
  <link>
    <name>res/raw/demo</name>
    <type>1</type>
    <location>C:/Development/Android/project/res/raw/demo.sqlite</location>
  </link>
  <link>
    <name>res/raw/demodatabase</name>
    <type>1</type>
    <location>//server/common/applicationname/DemoDatabase/demo.sqlite</location>
  </link>
</linkedResources>
```

Is there something I need to do so that I can leave the file on the fileserver, or do I need to copy it to be project local?

Comment: Are you trying to import your `demo.sqlite`, and use it in your app?

Comment: yes, I'm wanted to copy it from the .apk to the device so it can be used. I was just hoping to use a common file from the server as the source so my IOS and Android apps use the same source file and I don't need to have some additional build step to copy the latest from the server.

InputStream demoDatabase = getResources().openRawResource(au.com.applicationname.R.raw.demodatabase);